# Регулярное выражение от =begin до опционального =end

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить регулярное выражение возвращающее текст от =begin и до =end, причем если =end отсутствует, то нужно вернуть весь текст после =begin до конца richTextBox (C#).

Comment: А через позиции стартового/стопового маркеров и парочку ifов не проще ли?

Comment: Можно немного кода?

Comment: @Eugene, вот вы правильный вопрос задали про код :-) и еще добавьте пример входной строки и выходной:)

Comment: Вы напишите хотя бы что попробовали сделать сами и что не получилось, а мы подскажем в каком направлении двигаться дальше:)

Comment: Тут код можно писать только в одну строку, если нет, то объясните как

Comment: @Eugene нельзя. Строковые операции (как и все остальное) вам предстоит выучить (о ужас!) самому.

Comment: Не понял Вас, я спрашиваю, можно ли здесь написать код нормально, в несколько строк?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов _"и парочку ifов не проще ли?"_ -- паттерн `(=end|$)` - короче.

Comment: @Eugene: А почему вы не прочитали справку перед тем, как задавать вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "text =begin ...";
var m = Regex.Match(str, "=begin(.+?)(=end|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
m.Groups[1].Value;    // " ..."
```

Comment: не подскажите, как в комментариях писать многострочный код?

Comment: @Eugene комментарии не поддерживают многострочный код.

Comment: тут в коментариях не получится.  
а в тексте вопроса/ответа в конце строки ставите два пробела и enter.

Comment: Если в очень большом тексте есть `begin=`, но нет `=end`, это регулярное выражение может привести к ошибке. См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/wA6uR3/1).

Comment: @stribizhev _"это регулярное выражение может привести к ошибке. См. демо."_ -- демо работает в браузере. проверьте работу в прогр на c# - работает без ошибок.

Comment: ОК, проверил, работает. Однако в 46 раз медленнее, чем мое регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 3):

Использование ленивого квантификатора с точкой чревато выраженным замедлением работы программы в случае, если в тексте присутствует начальный разделитель, за которым следует большой кусок текста, после которого нет конечного разделителя.

Чтобы избежать таких проблем, рекомендуется использовать развернутый ленивый квантификатор (unroll-the-loop technique).

Для данного случая, нам нужно сначала найти `=begin`, а потом любой текст, не начинающий собой последовательность `=end`:

```
=begin([^=]*(?:=(?!end)[^=]*)*)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Объяснение**:

- `=begin` - буквальная последовательность `=begin`
- `([^=]*(?:=(?!end)[^=]*)*)` - захватывающая подмаска №1, которая находит 0 и более символов, отличных от `=` (`[^=]*`), за которой следует 0 и более последовательностей знака `=`, после которого нет `end` (см. `=(?!end)`), а после этого снова следует 0 и более символов, отличных от `=`.

**Сравнение** на сайте [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) ([строка в тесте тут](https://regex101.com/r/wA6uR3/1)):

`=begin([^=]*(?:=(?!end)[^=]*)*)` (2551 и/с) быстрее `=begin(.+?)(=end|$)` (53 и/с) в ~46 раз!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для получения всех вхождений (даже не надо использовать `RegexOptions.Singleline`):

```
var str = "My string with =begin...=end ... =begin...";
var results = Regex.Matches(str, "=begin([^=]*(?:=(?!end)[^=]*)*)")
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: а если сделать просто: var si = str.indexOf("=begin"); и var ei = str.indexOf("=end", si); на сколько быстрее чем regex?

Comment: На самом деле, код будет несколько иной, его будет больше. Не тестировал, но, скорее всего, будет быстрее.